# Error implementing google play services

Tags: java, android

Here is the code

```
    if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
            mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
            RC_SIGN_IN, R.string.signin_other_error)) {
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
    }
```

The error is wrong 5th argument type on R.string.signin....
It says required java.lang.String. How would i modify my code to get rid of the error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> getResources().getString(R.string.signin_other_error);

`getString` takes resource id and returns `String`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this, mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, R.string.signin_other_error))
```